# Stories sandbox in wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

Let's say I create a story dedicated to giving the weather in a given place, and a story dedicated to listing the possible activities in a given place, and a allowing to buy tickets for them.

Let's say a user launches the second story by entering "what can I do in Paris ?". Bot answers with a list of things and asks the user to input the one he'd like to buy a ticket for.

But, instead of entering a number, the user inputs "What is the current weather in Paris ?". Will the first story be triggered ?

A wit.ai blog post states :

> We strengthened the initial overfitting: when a user follows the
>   scenario of a story, the bot will 100% stick to the story.

Should we repost the intent as a context key so that the next action prediction scope stays within the same story ? Should all end of a story flush the context of all keys (which in our tests seems to be a very good idea not to stick to a story) ?

Thanks for any insights.